# Node + MySQL - How to get the raw query with bindings

Tags: node.js, node-mysql, fastify, node-mysql2

is it possible to get the raw SQL query with its bindings either prior or after execution to see what's about to, or has just executed?

Example:

```
const id = 4

const connection = await fastify.mysql.getConnection()
const [rows] = await connection.query(
    `SELECT age FROM users WHERE id = :id`, { id: id },
)
connection.release()
return rows
```

Is there a way to return:

```
SELECT age FROM users WHERE id = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading up on this subject, I expect it would be possible to get the sql by destructuring the result like this:

```js
const [rows, fields, query] = await connection.query(
    `SELECT age FROM users WHERE id = :id`, { id: id },
)

...

console.log(query.sql)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. The only variables available are ```rows``` and ```fields```.

Comment: hmm.. sorry. Maybe format the sql in a separate statement and then log en execute it? `connection.format(...)`